# Adding different JComboBoxes for different cells in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

Say I have an object representing a Person.
Each person has a name, and a list of hobbies.

Now, I want to create a table with 2 columns for the list of persons that I have.
The first column will show the name of the person, and the second will show the list of hobbies in a combo box.

The thing is, I iterate over my list of persons in order to populate the table.
So I don't have a way to know at the beginning "row 1 will have combo box X, row 2 will have combo box Y and so on". I will only know these things at runtime.

Got any ideas?

Comment: A combo box is a poor choice for display a list of...anything, because you can only see one item at a time.  Assuming that the `Person` can have more the one hobby, you may want to simply list them all or, provide a `JList` that will display them when the `Person` is selected, which would be (slightly) better than what you are doing, as the user would need to select a `Person` and then open the combo box to see the list....If they don't need to be editable, this would mean you could use two `JList`s instead...

Comment: I understand that, but there is a point to this thing. I need the user to select one hobby. (I know it sounds weird, but I just wanted to make my question as simple as I can)

Comment: Ahh, well, that's different...is the list of hobbies set or does it change for each `Person`?

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)

Comment: The list is different for each person, that is why I asked. I am familiar with the option to set the same combo box for the entire column, but I want different combo boxes per entry.

Comment: Okay, then you will need to start with your own custom cell editor, with a `JComboBox` at it's base.  From there, each time a editor is activated, you will need to get the selected person and populate the combobox with the hobbies available to them...You're probably going to have to provide more context about the structure of your program before you will get a better answer then that...

Comment: I see. I just don't realize why JTable provides getColumn method but no getCell, or something more flexible. Why is there an object called TableColumn but no TableCell?

Comment: I don't think the designers saw the table as a spread sheet, but instead saw it as a table of values which would have a single type and assignable value.

Comment: Oh well, too bad for me :-)

Comment: Thanks for all your answers Mad Programmer, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Cell editing is provided by a `CellEditor`.  This basically means that each column will have the same cell editor.  There are ways around this, but lets keep it simple.

Assuming that the list of hobbies is finite, and the list is the same for all people, it would be a simple matter to create a `JComboBox` based `CellEditor` and apply it to the table

Start by taking a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)

[image: combo box editor]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Hobbies {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Hobbies();
    }

    public Hobbies() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>(25);
                people.add(new Person("Mellisa"));
                people.add(new Person("Annabell"));
                people.add(new Person("Margarita"));
                people.add(new Person("Steve"));
                people.add(new Person("Christel"));

                DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox(createHobbiesComboBoxModel()));

                PersonTableModel model = new PersonTableModel(people);
                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(editor);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public ComboBoxModel createHobbiesComboBoxModel() {
        String[] hobbies = {"3D Printing",
            "A vintage scrapbook",
            "Amateur radio[1]",
            "Baton twirling",
            "Cleaning",
            "Computer programming",
            "Cooking",
            "Coloring",
            "Cosplaying",
            "Creative writing",
            "Crocheting",
            "Cryptography",
            "Dance",
            "Digital arts",
            "Drama",
            "Drawing",
            "Drinking Coffee",
            "Eating",
            "Electronics",
            "Embroidery",
            "Foreign language learning",
            "Gaming (tabletop games and role-playing games)",
            "Gambling",
            "Genealogy",
            "Homebrewing"};
        return new DefaultComboBoxModel(hobbies);
    }

    public class PersonTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Person> people;

        public PersonTableModel(List<Person> person) {
            people = new ArrayList<>(person);
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return people.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return columnIndex == 1;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            String value = null;
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    value = "Name";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value = "Hobby";
                    break;
            }
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 1) {
                Person person = people.get(rowIndex);
                person.setHobby(aValue == null ? null : aValue.toString());
                fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Object value = null;
            Person person = people.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    value = person.getName();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value = person.getHobby();
                    break;
            }
            return value;
        }

    }

    public class Person {

        private String name;
        private String hobby;

        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setHobby(String hobby) {
            this.hobby = hobby;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getHobby() {
            return hobby;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the effort, but I actually meant different combo boxes for each person. Now I feel a little guilty for making you go through all that trouble in vein...

Comment: @user3926648 You can replace DefaultCellEditor with your own extension and swap the JComboBox model before returning depending on value